# Symfony. is there a library for a checking user persmission?

Tags: php, symfony

is there a built in/library for a checking persmission?

For example in wordress `current_user_can('edit_posts')`.

Or what if **security.yml** will contain this?

```
EDIT_POSTS: {}
EDIT_OTHER_POSTS: []
BLOGGER: [EDIT_POSTS]
MANAGER: [EDIT_POSTS, EDIT_OTHER_POSTS]
EDIT_USERS: []
ADMIN: [EDIT_POSTS, EDIT_OTHER_POSTS, EDIT_USERS]
```

And then check in controller.

```
$this->isGranted('EDIT_OTHER_POSTS');
```

Comment: would 'voters' work for you ?  https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html#how-to-use-the-voter-in-a-controller

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html

Comment: Is using my way is ok for simplier way?

Comment: there is a semantic difference between roles and permissions. obviously, every concept could be used in ways that are definitely not intended, so ... sure. but what's the actual question?